# Thread dump /stacks in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

In Hadoop DFSZKFailoverController, it takes a thread dump using /stacks url. What is this /stacks api? Is it an api of jvm or something else?

https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/tools/DFSZKFailoverController.java#L252

Answer (score 0):

It's "something else".

The JVM doesn't include an HTTP server for getting thread/heap/stack dumps

The Hadoop Namenode has a REST API that that code is using